# Remap "Get Help" fn (F1 key) to open specific app

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, keyboard-layout

The fn "?" (icon on the F1 key) on my laptop is useless to me, and I keep accidentally pressing it. So I want to remap it, not just disable it like here: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-f1-key-help-windows-10/

How can I remap it to open an app, using Registry (Sharpkey affects my Start key)? Or at least remap it to other key (Caps lock, Shift, Sleep fn will be awesome...)
My Laptop: HP Envy 13
    https://images.app.goo.gl/BcGMs8egzdDQD9X99

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [edit] your question to include the model of your laptop. FN keys are often hardwired and not addressable by software, though depending on your laptop, there might be an available BIOS setting.

Comment: @MMM the "?" fn can be disable and software triggered, so I think it can be remapped

Answer (score 0):

**The "Function" key can be turned off with a few simple steps.**

  Steps for Turning off the Function Key
- Step 1
  Look on your keyboard for the "Fn" key and hold it down. This is usually located on the bottom left corner of your 
  keyboard, next to the "Alt" key, depending on which model of computer you are using.
- Step 2
  Locate the "Num Lock" or "Num Lk" key, whichever way it may appear on your keyboard. 
  Press the "Num Lock" key at the same time as you are pressing the "Fn" key. 
  This should turn off the "Function" key.
- Step 3
  Hold down and press the "Fn" + "Shift" + "Num Lk" keys all at the same time to turn off the "Function" key, if the 
  above step didn't work. You may need to use the "Shift" key based on which model of computer you have.

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-can-i-turn-off-the-function-key

Comment: That's not how I wanted, your steps are for turning off all function keys, I wanted only the "?" to be remapped. Also, here's my laptop keyboard: https://images.app.goo.gl/Hr4cgRwWB3wU2ott7. As you can see, there is no Num Lock and the only way to change the key is through Registry or 3rd party apps.

Comment: @Phineas I mistakened the question mark "?" to mean you did not understand what the Fn key meant.

Comment: It's an icon on the F1 key, when I pressed I, it just opens a link, useless. I can disable it, but I want to make it more useful, turn it into a macro key perhaps

Comment: If you are looking for a good third-party tool which helps you, have you tried this site? https://www.raymond.cc/blog/make-certain-keys-on-a-keyboard-to-act-like-other-keys/

Comment: I have always liked this site also: snapfiles : search word "keyboard remapper" https://www.snapfiles.com/downloadfind.php?action=s&ref=2&st=keyboard+remapper

Comment: thank you for your help, I've have tried Sharpkey (mentioned above) and Keytweak and none of them are able to recognize the "?" key

Comment: @Phineas Have a look at this post "How to remap/disable annoying HP Envy special function keys Discussion in 'HP' started by moviemarketing, Apr 26, 2010." http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-remap-disable-annoying-hp-envy-special-function-keys.479402/